# kcachegrind: there is no source available for the following function

Tags: c++, profiling, kcachegrind, callgrind

I am trying to view the annotated source using `$ valgrind --tool=callgrind ./myProgram` followed by `$ kcachegrind` using Ubuntu 12.04 (and I'm having the same problem with `$ qcachegrind` using Mac OSX).

The C++ script `myProgram.cpp` makes calls to functions that live in a `.hpp` file (via `#include "../include/myHeader.hpp"`, etc.).  I compile `myProgram.cpp` like this:

```
g++ -g -o myProgram myProgram.o -l<some third party lib>
```

where I don't care about viewing annotated source for that third party lib.

**What I would like to see is annotated source**  for the functions in `myHeader.hpp` and for `myProgram.cpp`.

**Instead, I see** kcachegrind's Flat Profile window with a list of all the functions that get called, including the functions in `myHeader.hpp` - *this is great*.  Now, kcachegrind reports the location of functions from `myHeader.hpp` as being from `myProgram` - *this is odd*.  And finally, when I select any function from the Flat Profile window and request to see Source Code, I am met with:

```
There is no source available for the following function
<name of the selected function>
This is because no debug information is present.
Recompile the source and redo the profile run.
The function is located in the ELF object:
<some location...>
```

**What I've tried:**

- added the directory holding `myHeader.hpp` to the Annotations list using kcachegrind's GUI.
- compiled using -O0  to remove compiler optimizations

Comment: Provide a self-contained example that can be copied, pasted, compiled and ran through valgrind. We cannot possibly check what's wrong with `<some function>` at `<some location>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering my own question thanks to user [n.m.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-m) -  I discovered this while running a simplified example.  The problem was with my compilation instruction, I was compiling to an object file with `-g` rather than compiling to an executable with `-g`.

Here's a working example for how to get kcachegrind to show annotated source:

`main.cpp` lives in directory `someDirectory/example`

```
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "../include/header.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main() {
  double a=1.0; double b=4.0;
  double tol = 1E-10;
  double zero = -99;

  if (sin(a)*sin(b) < 0 && (b-a) >= tol)
  zero = bisect_sine(a,b,tol);

  cout << zero << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Header file `header.hpp` lives in `someDirectory/include`

```
// header.hpp

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double bisect_sine(double a, double b, double tol) {

  double c;
  int step = 0; int maxsteps = 100;
  while (step < maxsteps) {
    c = (a+b)/2.0;

    if (sin(c) == 0 || (b-a)/2 < tol)
      return c;
    if (sin(a)*sin(c) >= 0)
      a = c;
    else 
      b = c;

    step+=1;
  }
}
```

Makefile

```
# Makefile 
CXX = g++  
main: 
   $(CXX) -g -o main main.cpp
   chmod 700 main
clean:
  rm main
```

After all of this, simply run `make` (yielding the executable `main` that was compiled with debugging `-g`), followed by `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./main`.  This will produce the expected `callgrind.out.<PID>` file, which can be read by kcachegrind.  Source annotation will then be available for the `main()` function of main.cpp as well as for `bisect_sine()` from the header file.

So, **this turned out to be a compilation issue**.  If I understood more about compilation into executables, object files, shared objects, yada yada yada, I would not have gotten into this mess.

Comment: This was helpful, thanks!. Some improvements: You should either add `return c` at the end of `bisect_sine(...)` or specify the return type as `void`.  Also, to make this more of a minimal example, the `header.hpp` can be moved to the same folder of `main.cpp` and make the include "cleaner".